# Is it possible to write a query in SQL that will return a non null sample of size N from each column independently?

Tags: sql

Suppose you have a table with 2 columns

| Age | Gender |
| --- | --- |
| null | M |
| 18 | null |
| 20 | null |
| 30 | F |

Let's say I want to get 2 independent samples from each column that are not null

Output would be

| Age | Gender |
| --- | --- |
| 18 | F |
| 30 | M |

This structure works if each column has 2 non null samples to return, however if they do not then we could have the output return the values as arrays so if we wanted 3 non null values the output would be

| Age | Gender |
| --- | --- |
| ["18","20","30"] | ["F", "M"] |

I know I can use approx_top_k but it scans the entire column and gets the frequency which is more then I need, is there another way? And it has to work >1000 columns

Comment: Tag your question with the database system you're using; `sql` is too generic. `APPROX_TOP_K` could be Snowflake, or Azure Databricks, or possibly some other engine.

Comment: Actually I want to know for any engine which is why I didn't make it specific

Answer (score 3):

You could use something like

```sql
select * from 
    (select distinct age from table where age is not null) ages
    cross join 
    (select distinct gender from table where gender is not null) ganders
order by random() limit 2
```

Comment: Might distinct both inner selects incase duplicates exist? oof 1000 cross joins. 1000 columns...

Comment: Good idea with distinct, thanks. Cross join will be extremely painful, but I don't see much alternatives how question stated.

Comment: Not to mention having `(select distinct [column] from table where [column] is not null) [column]` 1000 times in the query (once for each column)... That's on the problem, not this solution, but still...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Why use distinct? I don't care about them being distinct I want to take a simple random sample of each column independently. And the cross join can be quite slow especially for large tables. I think the limit could go inside each set of parans which would make the join faster but what happens as we scale this out to 1000 columns?

Comment: @MJH, Since you didn't specify this in question, `DISTINCT` would be a better approach in general. If you'll sensibly limit inner queries cross join will be faster, but for 999 cross joins it still most likely will be painfully slow.

Comment: @MJH, If you plan to use it outside of db, I would advise you to create a generalized method like `get_random_person_characteristic` and generate random persons in your code one characteristic at a time (If you plan to get a rather small number of random people). If you want a large number - either way, you'll wait for a very long time.